# How to bind multiple parameters to MySQLi prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a variable number of parameters to insert and I got the error `(2031) No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement` after the warning `Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in SaveIntermediateData.php5 on line 49`.

```
$link = new mysqli( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME );
if( ! $link ) {
    echo "<h1>new mysqli() failed!</h1>";
    exit( 0 );
}
$queryText =
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visitors (".
        "id    VARCHAR( 512) CHARACTER SET ASCII NOT NULL,".
        "name  VARCHAR(  80) CHARACTER SET ASCII NOT NULL,".
        "value VARCHAR(4096) NOT NULL,".
        "PRIMARY KEY ( `id`, `name` )".
    ")";
$link->query( $queryText );
$queryText = "INSERT INTO visitors (id,name,value) VALUES ";
foreach( $_POST as $name => $value ) {
    $queryText .= '(?,?,?),';
}
$queryText  = substr( $queryText, 0, -1 );
$queryText .= ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES( name ), value = VALUES( value )';
$id         = session_id();
$stmt       = $link->prepare( $queryText );
if( $stmt ) {
    $param_nr = 1;
    foreach( $_POST as $name => $value ) {
        $stmt->bind_param( 'sss', $id, $name, $value ); //<<<<<<<<< line 49
    }
    if( $stmt->execute()) {
        echo '<h1>OK</h1>';
    }
    else {
        echo "<h1>(".$stmt->errno.") ".$stmt->error."</h1>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "<h1>".$link->error."</h1>";
}
$link->close();
```

I believe only the last `bind_param` is taken in account. In Java, it's possible to use an index to bind a parameter but I don't know such a method with `mysqli`.
I may create a full text query but I prefer use binding to avoid injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only call `bind_param` *once*, so you'll have to add all the params you want into an array, then call it via `call_user_func_array`.

Try this:

```
$params = array('');
foreach( $_POST as $name => $value ) {
    $params[0] .= 'sss';
    array_push($params, $id, $name, $value);
}

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);

if( $stmt->execute()) {
    echo '<h1>OK</h1>';
}
```

Comment: As a long time programmer but long time retired, I've forgotten much but I am working on this same question -  where in the answer does $id come from and how can it be done if you do not specify the variable names? That is, can they be based on the column names from the query, an array of values or on POST names? Also, when inserting single values into multiple rows, would the data type be a single value 's' or would it be one for each row, such as 'ssss' for four rows?

Comment: @DonP `$id` was declared in the question asked here.  The query was `INSERT INTO visitors (id,name,value) VALUE (?, ?, ?)` so I'm just allowing it to be called in a loop to set the values.